# Error during running npm run dev in nuxt/electron boilerplate

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i am using nuxt/electron for my one of the app. i installed fresh nuxt/electron boilerplate code using vue-cli and every time i run npm run dev its giving error below mentioned . other commands working like build and start but on dev server is not working .please help me

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 124ms3:21:32 PM

module.js:472
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\apps\nuxt\"F:\apps'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
 at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
 at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
 at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
 at bootstrap_node.js:538:3
module.js:472
 throw err;
  ^
```

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/express this is git url of template i used. but i didn't do any code just cloned using vue-cli ..